# Access Iframe content height onver cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I was trying to resize the Iframe height as per the iframe content height, the iframe src is cross-domain
My code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#survey_iframe").load(function() {
      var h = jQuery(this).contents().find("body").height();
      jQuery(this).height( h );
  });
});
```

I also tried the plugin https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer but no success,

```
iFrameResize({
log                     : true,
enablePublicMethods     : true
});
```

please suggest here.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote - it might not show much effort but it's not that worse either. @Teemu: see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using `postMessage()` which is a cross domain message exchange function.

#### Your iframe content would post a message

**Location:** `http://localhost2:8080/`

```
parent.postMessage(
    '{"height": '+ document.body.scrollHeight +'}',
    "http://localhost:8080"
);
```

It's sending a JSON object with an height attribute to `parent`, which is the Iframe's parent window.

*Note that `postMessage()` explicitly specifies localhost as the target domain*

#### Your containing page would listen for the message event

**Location:** `http://localhost:8080`

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e){
    console.log("iframe:load", JSON.parse(e.data));
}, false);
```

It could include the other page, located on another domain, like this:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost2:8080/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

You can then access the height in that parsed JSON object.

*Note that the containing page is loading the iframe from another domain (localhost2) which I've added to my `hosts` file for testing purposes*

- For security reasons you should check the `origin` (the URL that sends the message) in the message event and ignore every event from unknown origins.
- Your `postMessage()` call should specify the destination URL as precisely as possible.

The `postMessage()` feature is supported in all modern browsers down to IE 9: http://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage

MDN about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage

Comment: you are right but the iframe domain is a thrid party site address. I cannot do anything with iframe src.

Comment: I've added that line to show how the iframe-page is included - to show the domain name. ;) I'll edit my post and add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of Cross-Site Scripting restrictions, the only control you have over the iframe is the element it self and not the content. This is largely to prevent malicious "cloning".

If you want to resize the iframe it self, you can do so just like you'd normally manipulate any DOM element, if you are trying to touch any content in the iFrame, it crosses the rules of cross site Scripting and cannot be done.